# An issue with specifying a column "Percent" in SQL Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table with a column name `PERCENT`. I need to run an ordinary `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <my_table>
WHERE PERCENT = 100
```

However, I get this error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PERCENT'

Is there a way to indicate a column so the system accepts it as a column name instead of a function?

Comment: The **best** solution is to completely **avoid** using any of the [Reserved Keywords from T-SQL / SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as database, table, column names in your own database objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PERCENT` is a reserved word.  Use escape characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM <my_table>
WHERE [PERCENT] = 100
```

It is used, for instance, with `TOP` as in `TOP 100 PERCENT`.

Comment: In addition: you can find a list of reserved keywords here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 5):

Enclose the column name in square brackets (i.e. `[PERCENT]`) or the ANSI/ISO standard double quotes (i.e. `"PERCENT"`). This will allow you to use reserved T-SQL keywords in identifiers.

I suggest one avoid using [reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) as object or column names to avoid this requirement.